# Prevent from using system.reflection in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I wrote some code that compile in runtime C# code into assembly and stores it in memory in asp.net. After that it is possible to execute such compiled code.

Code to compile in runtime is written by user. It is always one class that inherits from base class I created. The problem is that user may have access to private fields and methods in this base class using reflection. So my question: is there a way to prevent using reflection?

Comment: Can we see some code. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't tried anything right now. I did some research and didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [ReflectionPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx) attribute in Framework Class Library which controls access to non-public types and members through the System.Reflection APIs. If you can apply this attribute to your generated assembly in your case, you can try to see if it works.

Comment: I'll stress Yiğit Yener's point - letting users write code which is then compiled and run on the server is *dangerous*. You're worried about accessing private fields? Also worry about calling `System.IO.Directory.Delete("C:\\")`. Pre-.NET 4.0, we had Code Access Security for this. In 4.0 and above, we have Security-Transparent Code. Read up on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191569(v=vs.100).aspx